# How to set HTTP headers in .htaccess only for IE 9

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I am not able to find and way to set some header in .htaccess file only if the browser is IE9.
Pseudo code for my requirement is:

```
if (IE 9) {
    header set (value)  
} else {
    header set (value)
}
```

Please suggest how I can achieve this in my .htaccess file.

Comment: Can you give an example of a header you want sent to IE9 along with its 'else' value?

Comment: for ie9 i want to set header("X-UA-Compatible: IE=EmulateIE8") and for other header("X-UA-Compatible: IE=Edge");

Comment: If you server serves PHP/ASP/etc pages, Why not use the `<meta http-equiv="">` tag? And set its `content` to what you need based on the useragent?

Comment: Yes, this can can be achieved using conditional comments for ie 9 but if i put meta tag inside conditional comment then ie9 ignores it.

Answer (score 8):

I got the solution after reading bunch of lines in Apache doc :) .Just include these lines in htaccess, Its working fine for me.

```
BrowserMatch "MSIE 9.0"  ie9
header set X-UA-Compatible "IE=EmulateIE8" env=ie9
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [this article](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/beyonddoctype) `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />` should give you the desired result regardless of which version of IE you're using.

Comment: Yes, it will achieve the same thing which i want but this meta tag i need to include in my template (e.g html) which i wanted to avoid. As i already mentioned conditional state for IE9  ignores this meta tag and without using conditional comment for IE it will execute for all IE version. SO i thought of to detect IE9  and set headers through htaccess.

Comment: That `<meta>` tag tells the browser to pretend that the the header specified was sent by the server. If IE9 ignores it then it doesn't matter where you send it from, it'll still ignore it.

Comment: It only ignores only if i have put this meta tag inside conditional comments. Its weird but IE 9 is behaving the same, seems to be an issue with IE 9. Thanks.